# Is there credible evidence for Proto-Indo-Uralic?

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, uralic

Proto-Indo-Uralic is possibly an ancient language that was spoken around ten thousand years ago. I have heard that this has evidence but it hasn’t been proven. So, is there any real evidence (archaeological, comparative etc.) for the existence of such a protolanguage?

Comment: This question has a lot of overlap with that one: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34326/could-proto-indo-uralic-be-reconstructed?rq=1

Comment: Not really, that is about reconstruction. This is about proof of existance

Comment: Note that I did not cast a "close as duplicate" vote, I just want to have the link to the other question here (and prominently in the sidebar).

Comment: Reconstruction and proof of existence for an unattested language are very closely related. Because we have no attestation, any proof must be purely implied, and the best way to show that it should exist is that existence would explain something, usually correspondences. Those correspondences might also imply a form they might have both come from.

Comment: That seems true. But there could be archaeological finds that support PIU.

Comment: They wouldn't support it, they'd simply be consistent with it. But since languages leave no archaeological traces, they can't support any particular language family.

Comment: These are just two sides of the same question. If there's evidence it can be (at least partially) reconstructed. If it can be reconstructed there must be evidence.

Comment: This question is asking for the evidence that is not yet enough to reconstruct or otherwise prove the supposed genetic relationship. So it's only identical to the other Q if it can be reconstructed--but it cannot, sofar. This Q says as much; could use a supporting reference though.

Comment: For claims that there is evidence, Kloekhorst, Pronk et al. attempt to surmise somany (https://brill.com/view/title/55752), see e.g. the open access chapter by Peyrot (https://brill.com/view/book/edcoll/9789004409354/BP000013.xml). I'm affraid summing these up any further would be prohibitively difficult, or trivializing.